# Post HTML content

Tags: php

I have a page that contains html that is assembled via JS from user input. I need to post a block of that formatted HTML back to the same page, in order to process it with PHP.

For some reason having a blank moment and need a bit of a nudge.

Here's what I've got:

**mypage.php**

```
<?php 
... 
echo 'my html block';
...
echo '
<form method="post" action="'.PHP_SELF.'">
   <button type="submit">Post HTML</button>
</form>';
```

How do I copy and post it?

Comment: `action=""` will default to this form or `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >`

Comment: "How do I copy and post it?" well... i can't understand it.

Comment: `PHP_SELF` should not be used as it can be [user compromised](https://html.form.guide/php-form/php-form-action-self.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work :

1) create a hidden input field in the form

2) make sure the JS-generated HTML is enclosed in a  section with a unique ID, say "myUniqueID".

3) change your  from submit-type to action ; as action, trigger a JS function that copies the content from document.getElementById("myUniqueID").innerHTML to the hidden input field in your form

4) after the copy, fire the submit() method of the form.

Upon reloading the PHP script, the $_POST field of the hidden input field holds the JS-generated HTML

Comment: Hmm, this is actually a great idea and fairly simple to implement. Thanks for the suggestion. I wonder if I need to encode /decode it before the post, something like base64...

Comment: I don't think so - but you could expect that some kind of automatic conversion to url-encoded format is made. Inverse is achieved using urldecode() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).
The notes say that $_GET is already decoded, but no word on $_POST.
I think a single debugger run will answer that question. Good luck !